# How to convert my text to markdown with Marked - the conversion 's not working

Tags: javascript, reactjs

it's a first time for me to post a issue in here, try to do my best.

In order to practice, I am doing single app to convert to markdown and I am doing in with React. I also wanted to practice the hooks

To do that I am using **Marked**.

I haven't got any error in my console, so maybe I've done something wrong. I thought i did not manage properly with the hooks (I only user useState()), but then I've tried to go back to a class, but the problem is the same, no conversion to markdown.
here i put my composant, thanks for you help

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import DOMPurify from 'dompurify';
import marked from 'marked';

function Main() {
  const [text, setText] = useState('');

  function handleTypeText(e) {
    setText(e.target.value);
    // console.log(e.target.value);
  }
  function updateMarkdown() {
    const textTransform = DOMPurify.sanitize(text);
    const __html = marked(textTransform);
    return { __html };
  }
  return (
    <div id="container">
      <div id="left-container" className="left-textarea">
        <h3 className="subtitle-box">Text</h3>
        <textarea
          className="markdown-content"
          rows={15}
          cols={60}
          placeholder="Type your text in here"
          value={text}
          onChange={handleTypeText}
        />
      </div>
      <div id="middle-container" className="middle-area" />
      <div id="right-container" className="right-textarea">
        <h3 className="subtitle-box">Markdown preview</h3>
        <div dangerouslySetInnerHTML={updateMarkdown()} />
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: I don't understand what is not working. I tried to replicate your code and it worked. See here if this is what you get: https://codesandbox.io/s/react-marked-eb7uk . I've written ```_marked_, **is working**``` and it worked

Comment: @Diogo Peres - in fact, it worked on codesandbox, but I don't know why I don't see it on my browser,  I ve tried on Chrome and Moz..but thanks for trying on your side, as I wouldn't  think to try there. Maybe if I build the prod the problem won't be on